# Using vector Illustrations is haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sin, image, drawing, cartoon

I know that it is not permitted to draw anything that depicts `animate beings` but I really need a bit of help about my situation as my `income` will going to be generate from this work.

[image]

Recently I got a task where I have to develop a website but since it include these human figures in it as shown above. I am not the one who created it but as I mentioned I am going to use these kind of vector art in my website and this website will generate income for me.

So, is it okay to use these images or will I be part of the sin?

I am afraid of the punishment mentioned for drawing the animated beings that why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

The injunction is against idolatry; this, at the time of the Prophet (pbuh) was signified by carved idols. And hence the injunction against images.

So long as the intention is not to worship the image there is nothing wrong with using images. And how they are constructed - whether by drawing, by paint, by digital graphics or by photograph is besides the point.

In Islam, *niyyah* (intention) is important.